# How to use System functions in c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, ubuntu, system

I'm new to linux and I'm learning c++ how could I use system("") on linux
like 
system("color 4a");
how could I use this on linux

Comment: What do you think the `system` function is doing? What are you trying to achieve? What should `color 4a` be doing?

Comment: Could you be more specific about your goal/problem?  Or give some more context?

Comment: I want to use the function system on linux I use eclipse
not just color I want any command from system function but it gave me an Error

Comment: You really need to work on your question-asking-skills. You already said you want to use `system`, we asked you for more details. But instead of giving more details, you've just repeated something that is already in the question title and body… and isn't helping at all. What kind of trouble do you have? Do you get any errors? If so, which? If there are no error, what other problems are there? What is your goal, what do you want to use `system` for (maybe there's an alternative to achieve what you want)? We can't help you if you don't tell us what's wrong _exactly_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `system` just like any other function. The only caveat is that the command you are executing must be available on the system your application is running on *and* within the same context your application is being executed.

```
int main()
{
    system("color 4a");
}
```

The above code will execute the command `color` and pass it a single argument `4a` *if* the `color` command is available.

Comment: But this work on windows when I'm trying to run it on linux it gave me an Error

Comment: _"command you are executing must be available"_ - apparently it's not available on Linux.