# How to use c function system(command) and escape character "\3" on Linux

Tags: c, linux, centos

I wrote code using CodeBlocks on Windows. But I met with problems when I run the code on Linux, using its GCC compiler. While using the function `system("title heartshape")` and `system("color XX")` on Linux, it shows this error continuously :

> "sh: color: command not found"

Line 12 to 43 in the code are ones that can draw a heart shape, which is unused in this problem, and the `for(;;)` loop after that can change the color of the heart shape over time continuously.

The source code is as follows:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define I 20
#define R 340
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, e;
    int a;
    long time;
    system("title Heartshape");
/*codes that use to draw a heart, unhelpful to my question*/
    for (i = 1, a = I; i < I / 2; i++, a--)
    {
        for (j = (int)(I - sqrt(I * I - (a - i) * (a - i))); j > 0; j--)
            printf(" ");
        for (e = 1; e <= 2 * sqrt(I * I - (a - i) * (a - i)); e++)
            printf("\3");
        for (j = (int)(2 * (I - sqrt(I * I - (a - i) * (a - i)))); j > 0; j--)
            printf(" ");
        for (e = 1; e <= 2 * sqrt(I * I - (a - i) * (a - i)); e++)
            printf("\3");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 80; i++)
    {
        printf("\3");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= R / 2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 || i % 3)
            continue;
        for (j = (int)(R - sqrt(R * R - i * i)); j > 0; j--)
            printf(" ");
        for (e = 1; e <= 2 * (sqrt(R * R - i * i) - (R - 2 * I)); e++)
            printf("\3");
        printf("\n");
    }
/*codes that use to change the color of the heart*/
    for (;;)
    {
        system("color a");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color b");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color c");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color d");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color e");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color f");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 0");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 1");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 2");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 3");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 4");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 5");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 6");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 7");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 8");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);

        system("color 9");
        for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's the whole source code of my project.

The code can be run perfectly on Windows compiler, but keep showing the error `sh: color: command not found`on Linux.

In my limited experience with Linux for just a week, I can only assume that there're differences between Windows and Linux while using `system()`in c, and the escape character `\3` won't show on Linux as well.

I've found the [relevant question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709085/how-to-use-system-functions-in-c-on-linux), but the question seems remain unsolved, at least the answer doesn't help me. Other answers seems too complicated to solve this question.

I wanted to know the differences in using the function `system()`,as well as if there's any good practice to change the color of the heart shape continuously on Linux? Or are there alternatives for this?

Comment: set the environment variable PATH to an appropriate value.

Comment: Windows have its own commands, very different from the POSIX command of any standard Linux or macOS system. On a Linux (or macOS) system you're better off using so-called [ANSI escape codes](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html) that you simply print.

Comment: Also note that `system()` starts a brand new independent shell in its own process, so many commands you execute using it (especially on Linux or macOS systems) won't have any effect on your running program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your answer sincerely. So you mean that In the function's regard, Linux and Windows are completely different? Than I need to do further research on the differences between Windows and Linux afterwards...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Could you please explain it more specifically? I'm new to Linux so I'll appreciate it if the solution can help to solve the problem. Even relevant documents and questions could help, too.

Comment: Are you thinking of [ANSI colours for terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C or gcc.  The question is "On Windows there is a command called `color`.  Is there an equivalent command on Linux?"  You would obtain an equivalent result simply by typing `color` to your Linux command shell.  You don't need any C code to exhibit this.

Comment: the line `for (time = 0; time < 99999999; time++);` should probably use sleep

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for explaining how does the `system` command works in both systems, that solve my questions about how does the command work in c. However I find that system command that changes colors on Linux such as `tput setab 10` can only change a lines which comes next, instead of the whole terminal. That's the biggest problem for me in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the function `system()`, even though it does different things under the hood. Of course, because Windows and Linux are different operation systems. But as a standard library function, it generally does the same for you on both systems: it lets the command processor of the OS execute an internal command or launch another program.

The problem is with the programs (commands) you try to execute. The commands "title" and "color" are unknown to my shell (bash on Arch Linux), but are known to Windows' shell ("cmd.exe").

A similar issue is your output of `'\3'`. This special character is only shown with the specific font of your shell.

You need to take another approach. There are several possible solutions, for example using "ncurses" as an OS independent library.

Comment: Thank you for your attentive help, the answer perfectly solve my question. Then I need to learn more about different commands due to different shells between Windows and Linux later I guess.